# No value supplied for the SQL parameter, ']' added

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, named-parameters, unnest

I have a query that starts with
WITH o_id AS (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[:orderids]) AS id) SELECT ...

In java code I have
List orderIds=getOrderIds();
params.addValue("orderids", orderIds);

I'm getting 
Exception No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'orderids]': No value registered for key 'orderids]'
Looks like Spring adds the bracket to the name of parameter.. How can I pass the orderids to the query?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out an added space makes it work
WITH o_id AS (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[:orderids ])
notice the space between ':orderids' and ']'
Looks like Spring bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add curly braces around the parameter name like this:

```sql
SELECT unnest(ARRAY[:{orderids}]) AS id
```

Or, as you've discovered, you can add spaces around the parameter declaration like this (though, only the space *after* the parameter declaration matters for parsing):

```sql
SELECT unnest(ARRAY[ :orderids ]) AS id
```

---

I've found that IntelliJ's SQL parser incorrectly considers the curly braces to be a syntax error, so I use the space option.